# how can I add a borderline to a plotBand when mouse move in and remove that borderline when mouse move out?

Tags: highcharts

I would like to use the member function addPlotBand to add in a plotBand, and certain events like "mousemove, mouseout and click" to track the mouse. My question is that how to give the plotBand a border when mousemove in and get rid off the border when mouse move out of the plotBand?

thank you.

Comment: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.events has events such as `mouseOver` and `mouseOut`.

Answer (score 0):

Plot bands are SVG paths in Highcharts. They're stored in axis' `plotLinesAndBands` array and can be accessed like this:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var axis = this.xAxis[0];
        console.log(axis.plotLinesAndBands[0].svgElem.element);
      }
    }
  },
```

You can use Highcharts' `SVGElement.attr()` function together with `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events of SVG elements to handle adding/removing borders for plot bands.

**API reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr